# How to retrive data from database in Odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-8

I am new in Odoo 8, i am trying to create website with dynamic table (Using ul and li),

i don't know how to retrive data from database,

Can anyone help me how to do this?

**init**.py :

```
import controller
import books
```

**opener**.py

```
{
'name': 'Book',
'version': '1.0',
'category': 'Tools',
'summary': 'Test Book',
'description': "",
'depends' : ['base'],
'data' : ['views/book.xml'],
'images': [],
'qweb':[],
'installable' : True,
'application': True,
}
```

controllerA.py :

```
import openerp.http as http
from openerp.http import request

class Book(http.Controller):
@http.route('/page/getjson/', auth='public')
def index(self, **kw):
   Books = http.request.env['x_book.book']
   return http.request.render('book.index', {
        'books': Books.search([])
   })
```

books.py (model) :

```
from openerp import models, fields

class books(models.Model):

_name = "x_book.book"

name = fields.Char(size=32, string="x_name")
desc = fields.Char(size=32, string="x_desc")
```

book.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<template id="index">
    <title>Academy</title>
    <ul>
      <t t-foreach="books" t-as="book">
        <li><t t-esc="book.name"/></li>
      </t>
    </ul>
</template>
</data>
</openerp>
```

I am getting this error message when I hitting this url  http://localhost:8069/page/getjson

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try This code:
may be it's Work.

```python
from openerp.addons.web import http
from openerp.addons.web.http import request

class Book(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/page/getjson/', type='http', auth='public', website=True)
    def index(self, **kw):
        Books = request.env['x_book.book']
        return request.render('book.index', {
        'books': Books.search([])
   })
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error message,   "search() takes at least 4 arguments (2 given)"

Answer (score 1):

Extracting from [building a website](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/website.html) howto, assuming you have a controller querying ORM and returning a recordset of `academy.teachers` within a variable called `teachers`

```
class Academy(http.Controller):
@http.route('/academy/academy/', auth='public')
def index(self, **kw):
    Teachers = http.request.env['academy.teachers']
    return http.request.render('academy.index', {
        'teachers': Teachers.search([])
    })
```

You can create your list with

```
    <template id="index">
        <title>Academy</title>
        <ul>
          <t t-foreach="teachers" t-as="teacher">
            <li><t t-esc="teacher.name"/></li>
          </t>
        </ul>
    </template>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply eLBati, I am getting internal server error

Comment: You should look at what odoo server log says